# Facebook API datamining - supporting website cost with ads

Tags: facebook-graph-api, currency

I have a project prototype that is pulling event data from the Facebook Graph API, so no personal information is being acquired. It is mostly an aggregation of event data to streamline searching for times, location, event names and performers.

However I would like to support the running of the website costs, firstly with a few ads on the side.

The Facebook policy page https://developers.facebook.com/policy section 3.9 states:

> Don't sell, license, or purchase any data obtained from us or our
>   services.

Secondly, I am planning on making referral links so that if the User uses my website and clicks on a buy ticket link for example, then the link to the events ticket page will refer my website.

I am not selling the data but I am not sure how the law applies to making money from their data indirectly, am I complying with the Facebook policy since Facebook do not gain anything from my service?

Comment: Showing the data to users should be fine (as long as you keep it up-to-date) - but interfering with the tickets links the event creator might have configured sounds rather shady.

Comment: I mean having spoken to the event creator/ticket seller and have an agreement for a "finders fee" sort of thing